# Using DataSource Without Data URL

Tags: java, json, gwt, datasource, smartgwt

I have a legacy situation whereas the software currently transforms the returned response into an internal `JSON` formatted String. Is it possible for a `DataSource` to operate on a `JSON` formatted String for read-only purposes? The `DataSource` would be used to populate a `ListGrid`. How can I set the data URL to a String in memory? Would it be better to add the data manually to the `DataSource` using `addData()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I determined that I was able to use the SmartGWT utility class JSON to decode my JSON into a custom `JavaScriptObject`.

```
import com.google.gwt.core.client.JavaScriptObject;

public class MyStatusResults extends JavaScriptObject
{

   protected MyStatusResults()
   {
      // Intentionally empty
   }

   /**
    * Returns the total number of results for this search.
    *
    * @return the total number of results for this search.
    */
   public final native int getTotalResults() /*-{
   return this.total;
   }-*/;

   /**
    * Returns the entry results of the search.
    *
    * @return the entry results of the search.
    */
   public final native MyStatus[] getResults() /*-{
   return this.entries;
   }-*/;
}
```

Comment: Perhaps you could have a look to RestDataSource.

Comment: @AlainBUFERNE: Thanks for the suggestion. I am going to do that for some other services, but this one is a little different.